# Moshi throwing Exception "Unable to create converter" with minify enabled

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, okhttp, moshi

Moshi is throwing this exception:

```
Unable to create converter for com.xxxx.app.xxxx.xxxx.main.moshi.SingleData<ActorEntity>
```

But only in **debug** *environment* !!

In **release** *environment* is all working fine.

**How is that possible?**

FYI: I am currently updating my Moshi from version 1.3 to 1.9.3!

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: I don't think that was a code problem, it is working on release env but not if I switch to debug env.

Comment: A good stackoverflow question should have something more than a general description of the problem.

Comment: But I don't have any other Infos than this, just this exception message. @YuriSchimke

Comment: Well, a concise example of the code that causes this exception.  http://sscce.org/ is a good guide. 21 people have read this question, so implicitly there is a 20+ times leverage in spending the time improving the information content of your question.

Answer (score 1):

I found my issue, it was because I have to set:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true // <----- That was missing
    }

    release {
        minifyEnabled true
    }
}
```

I am new on Android so I have no idea what ProGuard was but you can read more: [her](https://github.com/square/moshi#r8--proguard) or [her](https://medium.com/@burakirenn/android-minifyenabled-obfuscation-and-shrink-9edcb4c6ffa4) or [her](https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/429)

Comment: This doesn't explain the issue. How come enabling obfuscation makes moshi create converters for the classes? I'm facing the same issue and I'm clueless right now.